# Как записывать в QByteArray по N бит

Tags: c++, qt, rtp

У меня есть задача декодировать RTP пакет и извлечь полезную нагрузку этого пакета (аудио данные). Для того, чтобы обходить все поля RTP заголовка, у меня есть вот такая функция:

```
quint32 readNBitsByRange(quint32 position, quint32 count, const QByteArray &array)
{
    quint32 accuml = 0;
    while (count != 0) {
            const quint32 l = (8 - position % 8);
            const quint32 u = (l < count ? l : count);
            const quint32 f = (8 - u);
            accuml  <<= u;
            accuml   |= ((*(array.data() + position / 8) << (8 - l)) & (((1 << u) - 1) << f)) >> f;
            position += u;
            count    -= u;
    }
    return accuml;
}
```

В качестве аргументов функция принимает позицию, откуда будет производиться чтение, количество бит и буфер, откуда и нужно произвести чтение. Благодаря этой функции я могу прочитать все поля RTP заголовка. Пример использования этой функции:

```
int main()
{
    // ... Откуда то получаем Rtp пакет в бинарном виде и записываем в QByteArray ...
    QByteArray array;
    for (quint32 i = 0; i < rtpBinaryDataLength; ++i) {
        array.push_back(rtpBinaryData[i]);
    }
    
    // 0                   1                   2                   3
    // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
    // +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    // |V=2|P|X|  CC   |M|     PT      |       sequence number         |
    // +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    // |                           timestamp                           |
    // +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    // |           synchronization source (SSRC) identifier            |
    // +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+
    // |            contributing source (CSRC) identifiers             |
    // |                             ....                              |
    // +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    
    quint16 rtpVersion   = readNBitsByRange(0x000, 0x002, array);
    quint16 rtpPadding   = readNBitsByRange(0x002, 0x001, array);
    quint16 rtpExtension = readNBitsByRange(0x003, 0x001, array);
    
    // .. И так далее ...
}
```

Все это работает! Но вот проблема!
Теперь у меня появилась задача записывать значения RTP пакета в QByteArray. Как мне это сделать, мне не известно! Известно лишь, что, например, в 1-й байт буфера нужно записать значения 4-х полей (V, P, X, CC) RTP пакета.

Хотелось бы иметь примерную функцию, как для чтения, чтобы легко можно было работать с ней.
Пример функции:

```
void writeNBits(quint32 position, quint32 count, quint32 val, QByteArray &array)
{
    // Устанавливаем позицию для начала записи
    // Записываем значение val
    // Count - указывает на то, что я хочу записать значение val в count бит
}
```

Comment: Вероятно вам поможет [bit field](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field)

Comment: @MaximTimakov Никогда не видел ничего подобного :) Спасибо большое, возможно мне это поможет.

Comment: а так не понятно, что означает `position`: то ли это в битах, то ли это индекс в `array`

Comment: @MaximTimakov `position` - позиция именно в битах. То и есть, если я хочу установить значение версии протокола, которая расположена в начале пакета и имеет размер в 2 бита, я бы использовал именно с такими параметрами функции: writeNBits(0x000, 0x002, 0x002, array);

А так бы выгледило использование функции, если бы я хотел установить в поле sequence number, значение 12345:

writeNBits(0x040, 0x010, 0x3039, array);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для заголовка можно создать структуру из битовых полей

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

//....

struct proto_head
{
unsigned V :2;
unsigned P :1;
unsigned X :1;
unsigned CC:4;
unsigned M :1;
unsigned PT:7;
uint16_t seq_n;
};

static_assert(sizeof(uint32_t) == sizeof(proto_head));

//... 
proto_head head;

head.V = 2; // etc
```

Поле `seq_n` нужно будет преобразовать к сетевому порядку байт:

```cpp
head.seq_n = htons(head.seq_n);
```

заполнив структуру можно будет преобразовать указатель на нее к `char*`

```cpp
auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&head);
```

и записать в `QByteArray`

```cpp
array.append(ptr, sizeof(proto_head));
```

**UPD:**

Изначальная структура `proto_head` содержит ошибку в порядке полей.

Как выяснилось правильным порядком будет следующий

```cpp
struct proto_head
{
unsigned CC:4;
unsigned X :1;
unsigned P :1;
unsigned V :2;
unsigned PT:7;
unsigned M :1;
uint16_t seq_n;
};
```

Нумерация битов в заголовке пакета, указанная в как RFC так и в Wikipedia, сбивает с толку.

Comment: Я попробовал Ваш вариант, и он работает. Но тут появляется другая проблема. Когда я создаю структуру и пополняю ее значениями, то они записываются не в нужном порядке. То и есть, при просмотре 12 байт RTP заголовка, я должен получить `80 88 E6 FD | 00 00 00 F0 | DE E0 EE 8F`, но я получаю `02 11 FD E6 | F0 00 00 00 | 8F EE E0 DE`. Если посмотреть на последние 8 байт, то я должен их отзеркалить. А вот на счет первых 2 байт я не могу понять, почему у меня получаются совсем другие значения. Я записываю: `V-2`, `P-0`, `X-0`, `CC-0` и должен получить `10000000`, но получаю `00000010`

Comment: Судя по [описанию](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) вариант с `02 11` всё же правильный: сбивает с толку нумерация бит слева направо

Comment: Для перевода в [сетевой порядок байт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) используются функции `htons/htonl`

Answer (score 2):

**Upd**

Немного поэкспериментировав с вышесказанными предложениями, я нашел более верный вариант записи `RTP` пакета в `QByteArray`. [Maxim Timakov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/209264/maxim-timakov) предложил создать структуру из битовых полей и после установки всех значений в данной структуре, преобразовать ее к `char *` и записать в `QByteArray`, за что, я благодарен, ибо это помогло, но к сожалению, от части.

Во-первых, использование такого вида записи структур в `QByteArray`:

```
RtpHeader rtpHeader;

...

auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&rtpHeader);
QByteArray array;
array.append(ptr, sizeof(RtpHeader));

...
```

является "грязным" способом записи данных.

Во-вторых, "в правильной последовательности" будут записываться лишь те значения, которые имеют фиксированный размер (`quint8`, `quint16`, `quint32`, `quint64`), а значения, которые имеют размер от 1 бита до 7, записать априори невозможно в `QByteArray` обычными средствами.

Поэтому, я написал примерный вариант правильной записи `RTP` пакета в `QByteArray`:

```
class RtpHeader
{
public:

    quint16 m_vp:0x02;
    quint16 m_pf:0x01;
    quint16 m_xf:0x01;
    quint16 m_cc:0x04;
    quint16 m_mb:0x01;
    quint16 m_pt:0x07;
    quint16 m_sn;
    quint32 m_tm;
    quint32 m_ss;

};

class RtpHeaderEncoder
{
public:

    RtpHeaderEncoder(void)                                noexcept = delete;
    RtpHeaderEncoder &operator=(const RtpHeaderEncoder &) noexcept = delete;
    RtpHeaderEncoder &operator=(RtpHeaderEncoder &&)      noexcept = delete;
    RtpHeaderEncoder(const RtpHeaderEncoder &)            noexcept = delete;
    RtpHeaderEncoder(RtpHeaderEncoder &&)                 noexcept = delete;
   ~RtpHeaderEncoder(void)                                noexcept = delete;

    static QByteArray encode(const RtpHeader &hdr)  noexcept;

};

QByteArray RtpHeaderEncoder::encode(const RtpHeader &hdr) noexcept
{
    QByteArray array;

    if ((hdr.m_vp == 0x02) && (hdr.m_pf == 0x00) && (hdr.m_cc <= 0x0F) && (hdr.m_pt <= 0x12)) {

        QDataStream stream(&array, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        stream << (((hdr.m_vp & 0x00003) << 0x01E)|
                   ((hdr.m_pf & 0x00001) << 0x01D)|
                   ((hdr.m_xf & 0x00001) << 0x01C)|
                   ((hdr.m_cc & 0x0000F) << 0x018)|
                   ((hdr.m_mb & 0x00001) << 0x017)|
                   ((hdr.m_pt & 0x0007F) << 0x010)|
                   ((hdr.m_sn & 0x0FFFF) << 0x000));

        stream << hdr.m_tm << hdr.m_ss;
    }
    return array;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    RtpHeader hdr;
    hdr.m_vp = 2;
    hdr.m_pf = 0;
    hdr.m_xf = 0;
    hdr.m_cc = 0;
    hdr.m_mb = 0;
    hdr.m_pt = 8;
    hdr.m_sn = 1;
    hdr.m_tm = 201452158;
    hdr.m_ss = 111537764;

    QFile file("./rawRtpHeader.bin");
    file.open (QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    file.write(RtpHeaderEncoder::encode(hdr));
    file.close();
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Этот способ и более безопасен и гарантирует правильное заполнение всех полей [фиксированного заголовка](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#section-5.1) `RTP` пакета. Если нужно заполнить `QByteArray` и полезной нагрузкой, то просто после заполнения массива заголовком пакета, мы записываем саму полезную нагрузку.

Comment: При таком методе записи использование битовых полей не обязательно. И вместо сложения(`+`) лучше использовать побитовое или(`|`)

Comment: @MaximTimakov На счет `|` согласен (не уследил). А на счет утверждения `При таком методе записи использование битовых полей не обязательно` я немного не согласен. Разве использование битовых полей не уменьшает и сам размер структуры ? Я понимаю, что идет речь о байтах, но все же :)

Comment: Нужно будет почитать RFC протокола. Но в описании чётко указано, что поле версии находится по смещению в ноль бит. А это значит что порядок полей в первом октете у Вас перепутаны.

Comment: @MaximTimakov Вы про этот участок кода ссылаетесь: `quint8 octet1 = (hdr.m_vp << 0x06) | (hdr.m_pf << 0x05) | (hdr.m_xf << 0x04) | (hdr.m_cc << 0x00);`

Comment: Битовые поля это сахар над битовми операциями. Для доступа к полю нужно как минимум наложение маски и сдвиг. Компилятор скрывает их.

Comment: Да, про этот участок.

Comment: @MaximTimakov Обновил :) Теперь это более верный вариант ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111976/discussion-between-maxim-timakov-and-withoutexperience).